# How to always connect to socket.io even when shutdown or exit the application to be able to receive notifications from calls or messages(React Native)

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io, react-native-webrtc

I'm having a problem with react native

my app can let you video call each other using webRTC and socket.io, the technologies i use are WebRTC, React Native, Socket.io , socket.io-client, react-native-webrtc

Basically the way my app works is when you open the app you automatically connect to socket.io to listen and make calls but when I turn off the phone screen or exit the app I can't hear and receive calls can call again because at that time the socket has automatically disconnected.

I want my application can still work properly even if I exit the application my application can still receive notifications of incoming calls from another person, can say I want my application Works like Messenger App

My current workaround is to find a way for each user's socket to always be connected to listen for incoming calls from others.

Has anyone encountered this problem or have a solution for this please let me know, I really appreciate it

Thank you guys, Have a nice day <3

Answer (score 2):

Move your socket to the Background service and then you can add the socket events in the service.

Note: This will increase your battery consumption.

Comment: How to move socket to Background service??